# How to create a pattern of numbers in excel using formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to get something like below in excel strictly by using formulae. Can someone let me know if this is possible in anyway?

[image: Click here for example of the requirement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example in `B2`:

```
=IF(COLUMN()-(ROW()-1)>0,COLUMN()-(ROW()-1),COLUMN()-ROW()+13)
```

Comment: this formula works also and will repeat the pattern infinitely. `=IF(MOD(COLUMN() - ROW() + 1, 12) = 0, 12, MOD(COLUMN() - ROW() + 1, 12))` Also if you instead use `ROW() - COLUMN()` the numbers will be ascending instead of descending.

Answer (score 3):

Because this repeats from 1 to 12, it can be based on `1+MOD(??,12)`

(`Mod`, or [Modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is basically the remainder when you divide a number.  You may recall in primary school, learning `7 ÷ 3 = 2 remainder 1` - this means that `MOD(7,3)=1`, or `7 mod 3 = 1`.  This also means that `MOD(12, 12)=0`, `MOD(13,12)=1`, `MOD(24,12)=0`, et cetera)

As it increases per Column, we can start with that:

```
=1+Mod(Column(), 12)
```

Since this starts at 3 in Column B, we need to subtract 2 from the Column:

```
=1+Mod(Column()-2, 12)
```

Now, that's the first row sorted.  What about the second?  Well, it *decreases* by 1 for each row - which, when working with `MOD`, will be the same as *increasing* by 11 (Because `12-1=11`)

```
=1+Mod(Column()-2 + 11*Row(), 12)
```

However, again, this is too high - because we start on the second Row, so we need to subtract 2 again:

```
=1+Mod(Column()-2 + 11*(Row()-2), 12)
```

Finally (as Marmiketin points out in comments) we effectively have the form `(X-2) - (Y-2)`, or `(X-Y)-(-2--2)`, which is `(X-Y)-0`, so we can remove both of the `-2` to simplify.  If you need to offset the Origin by a row or column, you just need to remember where to put them:

```
=1+Mod(Column() + 11*Row(), 12)
```

And, there we have it ☺

Comment: Effective and simple. Well done! If OP sees this, this is your answer!

Comment: Nice solution. pure math is always more satisfying. It could be made even simpler though by removing the - 2's as the diagonal of 1's in the table intersects with row1 column1. `=1+MOD(COLUMN() + 11*ROW(), 12)` If you want to shift the 1's over one column you just need to use row() +1 and if you want to shift the 1's down one row you need to use column() +1

Answer (score 1):

In **B2** enter:

```
=COLUMNS($A:A)
```

and copy across.  In **B3** enter:

```
=IF(B2=1,12,B2-1)
```

and copy across.  Then copy **B3** through **M3** downward:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

We can use a **single formula** if we make sure that *row#1* is always empty *(as it is in my illustrated example)*.

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1="",COLUMNS($A:A),IF(B1=1,12,B1-1))
```

copy this both across and then downward.

**EDIT#2:**

There should be another approach *(without using `IF()` statements)* using the `ROWS()`, `COLUMNS()`, and `MOD()` functions to get the same table.

It may even be possible to use `SEQUENCE()` if you have Excel 365.

Perhaps another person can look at it.

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student for the prompt answer and it seems to have helped to achieve the result. But for a long-term, would it be possible to achieve this by using a single formula?

Comment: @RohanGokhale  YES.  I will update this later............................

Comment: @RohanGokhale  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I'm looking at your logic and I like it! +. Also, maybe it's just me but something tells me there must be a pure maths way without `IF` =)

Comment: @JvdV: I was also looking out for a relation using the mathematics, but was not able to figure it out.

Comment: This looks nice as well @Gary'sStudent

Comment: @RohanGokhale  See my **EDIT#2:**